# Child padding falls outside the parent element

Tags: html, css

Applying padding to  child elements is making the child draw over the boundaries of its containing parent. Can you please explain the size consideration in margin, padding and content width.

If we increase the padding why don't the parent also resize to the accumulative size of all the children considering the child's padding also?

http://jsfiddle.net/NkXUW/4/

```
 <div>
       <ul>
          <li><a>srikanth</a>
           </li>
           <li><a>sunkist</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>sunday</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>



div {
     margin-top:90px;
    margin-left:90px;
    background-color:#676896;
   }
   ul {
     list-style-type:none;
   }
    ul li {
    display:inline-block;
   }
   a {
    background-color:#c34567;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
   }
```

What are coding practices that we need to consider to over come this problem.?

Ok guys I got lot answers that do work. Can anybody explain the parent size calculation based on child elements. what are characteristics of the child  that are considered while calculating  the encompassing parent's size. when the whole padding is considered when it not considered ?

Comment: none of the below answers worked for you?

Comment: Ok guys I got lot answers that do work. Can anybody explain the parent size calculation based on child elements. what are characteristics of the child that are considered while calculating the encompassing parent's size. when the whole padding is considered and when it not considered ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

the reason the child was overdrawing the boundaries of the parent is because the child is a tag of type `<a>` which by default is `display:inline` (you can see if that you go in chrome developer tools and see under computed style). an inline element displays like a line of text.. so the way it treats width and height and all that is very different than a block (a div for example is a block by default).

that being said, if you change the display setting of a to `display:inline-block` you get to keep the inline properties of `<a>` but at the same time also get the block properties, namely having a padding and width and height that is recognised by its parent node, which will then [expand](http://jsfiddle.net/NkXUW/11/) to accommodate it.

So there aren't any best practices about this. The only best practice is to understand what each display property mean (ie `inline` vs `block` vs `inline-block`) and put it to its proper use.

Answer (score 12):

Use `display:inline-block;`

```
a {
    background-color: #C34567;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

#### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NkXUW/8/)

> - An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it    tolerates HTML elements next to it.
> - A block element has some whitespace above and below it and does not    tolerate any HTML elements next to it.
> - An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same    line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 3):

Can be solved without making any change in `a` tag. Just add `overflow: hidden;` property to `div` element.

```css
div {
  margin-top:90px;
  margin-left:90px;
  background-color:#676896;
  overflow: hidden; /*expends its height if not fixed*/
}
```

Updated fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/NkXUW/52/

Answer (score 2):

You must do add `display: block;` to `<a>` element to expand parent as you need.
See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NkXUW/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

about different between margin and padding please read [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-between-margins-padding-css/) maybe it help you

I don't think this is correct `float` your `div wrapper`

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/NkXUW/6/)

```
div {
    float:left;
    margin-top:90px;
    margin-left:90px;
    background-color:#676896;
}
```

hope this help you..

Answer (score 0):

By default in CSS, an element's actual width and height is width + padding + border. Meaning, when we give an element a width of maybe 10px, the actual width of that element becomes 10px + padding + border. This is why giving it padding or border when it is already at 100% will cause an overflow.

1. Using CSS Box-sizing property
   Using box-sizing is the best way of tackling the issue of an overflow caused by padding.
   The box-sizing property will allow us to define how the width and height of an element are calculated. The default value of the box-sizing property is content-box, but when we set it to border-box this will make the element’s padding and border to also be included in its width and height.
   Meaning if we set the element as a width/height of 10px and add padding or a border of 2px, the element’s actual width/height will still be 10px except the padding + border is greater than 10px

   ```
   .div{
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px
     padding: 2px;
     border: 2px;
    }
   ```

Element's actual width = width + padding + border
Element's actual width = 10px + 4px + 4px = 18px

This is the same for the height.
Element's actual height = 10px + 4px + 4px = 18px

We used 4px instead of 2px for the border and padding because in our code we are adding 2px to both the left and right sides of the element.

But with the box-sizing property:

```
.div{
   width: 10px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   border-right: 5px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Element's actual width = 10px + 5px + 5px = 10px
Element's actual height = 10px + 4px + 4px = 10px

2. Using the CSS calc() function
   The calc() function allows us to perform calculations when we want to specify a property value. The cool thing about the calc() function is that even when the values are in a different unit, it can still be used to calculate the adding(+), subtraction(-), multiplication(*) and division of the values.
   For example, we can use the calc() function to do something like this:

   .div{
   width: calc(100% - 20px)
   }

For the overflow issue of adding padding to a 100% width/height element Using the calc() function is not the most efficient way of going about it but it will still suffice.

Here is how we go about using the calc() function to handle the overflow issue:

```
.div{
   width: calc(100% - 20px - 20px )
   height: calc(100% - 20px - 20px )
   padding: 10px
   border: 10px
}
```

Source: [https://dev.to/tammibriggs/two2-ways-to-prevent-padding-from-causing-an-overflow-in-css-4ain#:~:text=By%20default%20in%20CSS%2C%20an,100%25%20will%20cause%20an%20overflow](https://dev.to/tammibriggs/two2-ways-to-prevent-padding-from-causing-an-overflow-in-css-4ain#:%7E:text=By%20default%20in%20CSS%2C%20an,100%25%20will%20cause%20an%20overflow).