# Why don't list items size to fit their content?

Tags: html

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jr32b6zm/2/

I'm wanting to use a list to style a set of links that look like buttons. But when I add padding to the links, they don't make the containing `li` size larger. I can fix this by adding identical padding to the `li`, but it leaves me wondering why the `li` doesn't expand to fill its content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css child padding makes it draw out side the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424915/css-child-padding-makes-it-draw-out-side-the-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakenly you are adding padding to the `a` tag. Instead you need to add the padding to the `li`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>one</a></li>
</ul>
```

Still you want to use `a` tag for your css? Add `display:inline-block` to `a`.Learn more about [inline-block](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>one</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Small point: the reason for adding padding to the `a` as I understand is that's the area the browser considers for hit-testing. Adding padding to just the `li` means you have to click specifically on the text for the "button" to be clicked, which isn't what I want.

But `inline-block` does seem to be the answer!

Answer (score 0):

A `a` is an inline element and so is not affected by padding. You need to make the `a` a block level element for it to work:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block; // Add this line
}
```